# Get Sum of Values in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an array and each list item in that array is an object the has a value key. What I would like to do is add all of the values to get a total. I want to do this on the back end rather than the front end. I have tried the aggregate method, but haven't had any luck as it returns an empty array. Here is my array:

```
"budgets" : [
    {
        "name" : "check",
        "value" : "1000",
        "expense" : "false",
        "uniqueId" : 0.9880268634296954
    },
    {
        "name" : "car",
        "value" : "500",
        "expense" : "true",
        "uniqueId" : 0.1904486275743693
    },
    {
        "name" : "car2",
        "value" : "500",
        "expense" : "false",
        "uniqueId" : 0.23043920518830419
    },
    {
        "name" : "car23",
        "value" : "500",
        "expense" : "false",
        "uniqueId" : 0.014449386158958077
    },
    {
        "name" : "car235",
        "value" : "500",
        "expense" : "false",
        "uniqueId" : 0.831609656335786
    }
],
```

What I want to do is get the total of the values that have "expense" : "true" and the get a separate total of "expense" : "false" how would I do this? Like I said I have tried the aggregate method, but I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: What is the query you have been trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to using the aggregation framework commands you might not yet be aware of the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator. You can use this in order to get your totals separated:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Unwind the array to de-normalize the items
    { "$unwind": "$budgets" },

    // Group the totals with conditions
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "expense": { "$sum": { 
            "$cond": [
                "$budgets.expense",
                "$budgets.value",
                0
            ]
        }},
        "nonExpense": { "$sum": { 
            "$cond": [
                "$budgets.expense",
                0,
                "$budgets.value"
            ]
        }}

    }}

])
```

So what that will do is evaluate the `true/false` condition of expense as the first argument, and when the condition is actually `true` then the second argument of the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) will be chosen and passed on to the **`$sum`**. If the condition evaluates to `false` then the second argument is chosen.

But looking at your data you appear to have a problem:

```js
    {
        "name" : "check",
        "value" : "1000",
        "expense" : "false",
        "uniqueId" : 0.9880268634296954
    },
```

Noting here that all of the fields, and most notably the `expense` and `value` items, are all **strings**. So this is a problem as while we could get around evaluating the `true/false` values by doing string comparisons rather than direct boolean, you simply cannot co-erce a string as a number that can be passed to [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

So firstly you need to **fix** your data, unless it is not actually in the form as you have represented. But when it meets a correct form, then you can do your aggregation.

Comment: Ok great answers. I changed my data to include a number and boolean. These both do what I want them to do, however I realized that I need to target a specific budgets array, depending on the username. So username is a string such as { username : "myname", budgets : [ ... ]. So first I will need to target the object the username lives in and then get budgets.

Comment: @realseanp Somewhat baffled why you chose to accept an answer that splits the result into two documents, and more baffled why you would then ask more questions on the answer you did not accept. You have two choices really, which are modify the above so the group `_id` key is no the "$username" and that will aggregate for all users. Or use the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage first in order to select your particular username

Comment: It was a test of your commitment to the answer. You have passed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all covert you datatype of value from string to integer(summable) type and then use

```
db.collectioName.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$budgets"},

    {
    $group:{_id: "$budgets.expense",
    total: { $sum: "$budgets.value"}}
    })
```

and then you should get result like this

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "true",
            "total" : 500
        },
        {
            "_id" : "false",
            "total" : 2000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { "$unwind": "$budgets" },
                  { $match: { expense: "true" } },
                  { $group: { _id: "$_id",
                            name: { $addToSet: "$name" },
                            uniqueId: { $addToSet: "$uniqueId" }, 
                            total: { $sum: "$$budgets.value" } } }
               ])
```

Comment: Not actually what the OP asked for, which was separate totals. Also note that the contents are in an array so the field names and technique are off by a fair bit. See the answer I gave for usage of the $cond operator as well as the notes on the condition of the data.